# Using quartz to trigger job based on data added to database

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am already using quartz for my scheduled jobs so thought if I could leverage that implementation for triggering jobs based on data inserted in a table.

I want to trigger a quartz job when a new row gets added to a table.
The problem is that in my production environment I have seperate nodes for running quartz jobs and other application nodes.
So my application cannot trigger a quartz job directly. Instead I add the job in the database, now I want create a listner which looks at the table continously for changes which then fetches the job and triggers it.
Does quartz provide any such way to trigger adhoc jobs?

Comment: Am not aware of any out of the box quartz solution. one suggestion would be to have a job that runs every "N" mins, and scans the DB to find entries that were added since the last time the job ran.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going the route of creating triggers at the Database level. I would suggest you to fire an event in `@PostPersist` method in your entity and subscribe to the same event anywhere in your application, or if you are using Distributed Event Bus, you can subscribe to the event across the applications.

As a result, you can trigger any sort of job in your subscriber.